# What does "$\pi$-almost" mean?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, notation, measure-theory

I'm reading "Complex Stochastic Systems" edited by Barndorff-Nielsen et al. I found that they use the expression $\pi$-almost consistently throughout Chapter 1. I don't understand what $\pi$-almost means or how to read in plain English the sentences using this expression. Can somebody tell me how to interpret the sentences in the images?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that the event asserted in the limit theorems occurs [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) with respect to the probability measure $\pi$ --- i.e., the asserted event satisfies $\pi(\text{Event}) = 1$.
A useful intuitive way to read assertions of this kind is to read it as, "the limiting behaviour shown in the theorems holds, except possibly on a set of values of $x^{(0)}$ occurring with zero probability under the measure $\pi$".